# Simple 3D particle gravity in javascript?

Tags: physics, javascript, simulations

I'm trying to do some simple gravity handling in my 3D environment (I'm using three.js). I've got some code, but it doesn't work. I'm hoping it's just a silly bug somewhere. **Note: This is a cross-question from stack overflow since I've got no responses**

```
function handleGravity() {
    for(var j = 0; j < spheres.length; j++) {

        for(var i = 0; i < spheres.length; i++) {

            var r1 = new Array( spheres[j].position.x, spheres[j].position.y, spheres[j].position.z);
            var r2 = new Array( spheres[i].position.x, spheres[i].position.y, spheres[i].position.z);
            var r12 = new Array(r2[0]-r1[0], r2[1]-r1[1], r2[2]-r1[2]);
            var r12UnitVector = new Array( r12[0]/Math.abs(r12[0]), r12[1]/Math.abs(r12[1]),r12[2]/Math.abs(r12[2]) );

            var m1 = masses[j];
            var m2 = masses[i];
            var r12Squared = r12[0]*r12[0] + r12[1]*r12[1] + r12[2]*r12[2];
            var a12 = new Array( -(gravConst*m2/r12Squared)*r12UnitVector[0], -(gravConst*m2/r12Squared)*r12UnitVector[1], -(gravConst*m2/r12Squared)*r12UnitVector[2]);

            velocities[j][0] += a12[0]*timePassed;
            velocities[j][1] += a12[1]*timePassed;
            velocities[j][2] += a12[2]*timePassed;
        }

    }
}
```

If you can see anything wrong with it, or give me any tips on using JavaScript to simulate many particles in a 3D environment most **efficiently** (I'm very new to physics + simulation), that would be awesome!

Comment: What do you mean by "simulating gravity" ? Do you want to make animation of falling stuff, or just compute positions of objects after some time? Do you want objets to collide with each other?

Comment: Gravity between the particles. So they act like planets in space. I think I've solved it though - thanks

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work. It's a little clunky though - it makes me think there's some sort of rogue rounding going on:

```
function handleGravity() {
    for(var j = 0; j < spheres.length; j++) {

        for(var i = 0; i < spheres.length; i++) {
            if(i != j) {
                var r1 = new Array( spheres[j].position.x, spheres[j].position.y, spheres[j].position.z);
                var r2 = new Array( spheres[i].position.x, spheres[i].position.y, spheres[i].position.z);
                var r12 = new Array(r2[0]-r1[0], r2[1]-r1[1], r2[2]-r1[2]);
                var r12UnitVector = new Array( r12[0]/Math.abs(r12[0] + r12[1] + r12[2])/3, r12[1]/Math.abs(r12[0] + r12[1] + r12[2])/3, r12[2]/Math.abs(r12[0] + r12[1] + r12[2])/3 );

                var m1 = masses[j];
                var m2 = masses[i];
                var r12Squared = r12[0]*r12[0] + r12[1]*r12[1] + r12[2]*r12[2];
                var a12 = new Array( -(gravConst*m2/r12Squared)*r12UnitVector[0], -(gravConst*m2/r12Squared)*r12UnitVector[1], -(gravConst*m2/r12Squared)*r12UnitVector[2]);

                velocities[j][0] -= a12[0]*timePassed;
                velocities[j][1] -= a12[1]*timePassed;
                velocities[j][2] -= a12[2]*timePassed;
            }
        }

    }
}
```